# Issues with pthreads compling

Tags: c, linux, makefile, pthreads, gnu

It seems I'm having issues with the pthread when I try compiling with a Makefile:

```
/csapp.c:462: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
```

I think it might have something to do with the -lpthread?
Here is my Makefile (yes they are tabbed once):

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g 
LDFLAGS = -lpthread

OBJS = proxy.o csapp.o

all: proxy

proxy: $(OBJS)

csapp.o: csapp.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c csapp.c

proxy.o: proxy.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c proxy.c
clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o proxy
```

Comment: Do you see the `ld` command line go by when you `make`? I'm assuming that `-lpthread` isn't actually making its way to `ld`.

Comment: I get   `gcc -lpthread  proxy.o csapp.o   -o proxy
csapp.o: In function 'Pthread_create': `

Comment: Why is `Pthread_create` capitalized?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It's a wrapper function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is with `LDFLAGS`.

From [**10.3 Variables Used by Implicit Rules**](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html):

> `LDFLAGS` Extra flags to give to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the linker, `ld`, such as `-L`. Libraries (`-lfoo`) should be added to the `LDLIBS` variable instead.
>
> `LDLIBS` Library flags or names given to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the linker, `ld`. `LOADLIBES` is a deprecated (but still supported) alternative to `LDLIBS`. Non-library linker flags, such as `-L`, should go in the `LDFLAGS` variable.

So try:

```
LDLIBS = -lpthread
```